# :mnesia disk_copeis not working for my Elixir

Tags: elixir, mnesia

```
> alias :mnesia, as: Mnesia
> Mnesia.create_schema([node()])
> fields = [:id, :to, :from, :body, :format, :metadata]
> Mnesia.create_table(:mail, [attributes: fields, disc_copies: [node()]] )

{:aborted, {:bad_type, :mail, :disc_copies, :nonode@nohost}}
```

If I do

```
iex(5)> Mnesia.create_table(:mail, [attributes: fields] )
{:atomic, :ok}
```

Everything is fine, however this is only created in RAM

How do I make `:mnesia` to store on Disk.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mnesia isn't started correctly.

```
iex(1)> :mnesia.create_schema([node()])
:ok
iex(2)> fields = [:id, :to, :from, :body, :format, :metadata]
[:id, :to, :from, :body, :format, :metadata]
iex(3)> :mnesia.start
:ok
iex(4)> :mnesia.create_table(:mail, [attributes: fields, disc_copies: [node()]] )
{:atomic, :ok}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try naming your node first:

```
> iex --name foo
```

Then you need to make sure you start Mnesia. This worked for me:

```
alias :mnesia, as: Mnesia
Mnesia.start()
Mnesia.create_schema([node()])
fields = [:id, :to, :from, :body, :format, :metadata]
Mnesia.create_table(:mail, [attributes: fields, disc_copies: [node()]] )
```